# Postgres Like Using Select

Tags: postgresql

I want to use the `LIKE` function to see if there is a `character varying` value from another column within a different column. Is this possible?

I have tried the following with no luck (syntax errors)

`SELECT * FROM questions WHERE qaskedif like '%' || SELECT qlabel FROM questions WHERE qdefaultvalue IS NOT NULL || '%';`

Comment: Not sure I'm following - can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: `LIKE` will misbehave if the searched string happens to contains % or _ . Better use `position(smallerstring IN largestring)>0` as the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a self-join to get that kind of query:

```
select a.*
from questions a join questions b
on a.qaskedif like '%' || b.qlabel ||'%'
```

Note that this needs to do a cartesian join to evaluate, so it will be slow if the table is of any size